# Having a listener thread in a client

Tags: java, sockets

I have a client sever program but I need my client to be able to listen for messages from the sever as it may send some at any time. I also need my client send information when needed to. What would be the best way to do this? I understand I'd probably need a thread.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: By client, do you mean a GUI or a console program?

Answer (score 2):

If this is the only thing your client will do, you don't need a separate thread.
Otherwise, yes, you need one background thread to handle these tasks which would
free the main thread to do other things.

To create a thread, the most basic way is to extend `Thread` or implement `Runnable`.

See also:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/

Comment: The client will have two threads T1 (main) and T2 (background). You don't really need T1 to use the socket, this is the whole design idea behind T2 - that T2 would handle all the socket communication with the server.

Comment: So if like you can share the same socket between T1 and T2 but it sounds like a bad design idea to me.